# Возвращение String вместо int из метода

Tags: java

```
public class Coordinate {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int a = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        System.out.println(Coordinate(a,b));
    }

    public static int Coordinate(int a, int b) {
        int x = 0;
        if (a > 0 && b > 0) x = 1;
        if (a < 0 && b > 0) x = 2;
        if (a < 0 && b < 0) x = 3;
        if (a > 0 && b < 0) x = 4;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы метод `Coordinate` возвращал не число, а строку, если `х` поменять на `String`? При этом выполнив условия в методе.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String Coordinate(int a, int b) {

    String x = "0";
    if (a > 0 && b > 0) x = "1" ;
    if (a < 0 && b > 0) x = "2" ;
    if (a < 0 && b < 0) x = "3" ;
    if (a > 0 && b < 0) x = "4" ;

    return x;
}
```

Comment: попробуйте скомпилировать) не  получается так, конвертировать как-то надо

Comment: @wra4 этот код нормально компилируется и выполняется. И ничего в нём конвертировать не надо. `x` - это `String`, и метод возвращает `String`.

Comment: @wra4 я не вижу никакой проблемы, почему бы этот код не скомпилировался

Answer (score 1):

Как и сказали выше, ваш код и так удачно компилируется. Можете ещё попробовать так:

```
public static String Coordinate(int a, int b) {
        int x = 0;
        if (a > 0 && b > 0) x = 1;
        if (a < 0 && b > 0) x = 2;
        if (a < 0 && b < 0) x = 3;
        if (a > 0 && b < 0) x = 4;
        return String.valueOf(x);
}
```